# How to update Value of a TODO List from browser Local Storage every time i reload the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching

I have created this Task-List project in which a user is able to Add and Delete a task. I also added a functionality of saving the Task-List values to the browser Local-Storage, So when the page reloads the List Items still persist on the page. The problem that I am facing is that this functionality only works in Incognito Tab or when I hard reload the Normal tab. I think this is some cache related problem.?

Is there any way in which I can retrieve the list without any hard reloads and without opening in incognito tab.?

Below is the HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT code for the same.

```js
//Here we select the input whose value will be the name of new create list whithin list container.
var addItemBtn=document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
//Here we select the add button that adds the the value of above input to list container.
var inputItemName=document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
//Trigger an click event when we click the add buttton and call addListItem() function.
addItemBtn.addEventListener('click',addListItem);
//Here we select the list container.
var listContainer=document.getElementById('listContainer');
//Declare an object storing the list-item content and its corresponding count number.
    function addListItem(ev)
    {
        //This prevents the data of list from deleting when the function finishes its work.
        ev.preventDefault();
        //Check if the input field is empty or spaced or null
        if(inputItemName.value=="" || inputItemName.value==" "  )
        {
            //Display an error message on the webpage.
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML='<img src="error-image.jpg" class="error-img" alt="Hindustani Bhau"/>'+'Please Enter Some Value In The Text-Box.';
        }
        else
        {
            
            //Remove the error message from the page.
            document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML='';
            //Directly create the list items in innerHTML of listcontainer and increment it everytime.
            listContainer.innerHTML+=
            `<li class="listItem">
            ${inputItemName.value}
                <button class="closeBtn" onclick="removeListItem(this)">X</button>
            </li>
            `;
            
                //Store the contents of listContainer in local storage directly.
                localStorage.myListItems = listContainer.innerHTML;
           
            
            //Clear the input when we add a item.
            inputItemName.value='';
        }
        
    }
    
   
    //Function to remove the selected list item
    function removeListItem(e)
    {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to do this ?'))
        {
            //Deletes the parent li element of the given child node close button.
            e.parentNode.style.display='none';
        }
    }
        //When the body loads just append all values stored in local storage to the listContainer.
        document.body.onload=()=>
        {
            if(localStorage.getItem('myListItems')!=undefined)
            {
                //Retrieve data from local storage.
            listContainer.innerHTML=localStorage.myListItems;
            console.log("Item Persists");
            }
                
            
            
        }
```

```css
*
{
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
}
.main-heading
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5rem;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:lighter;
    color:#00bf8f;
}
#mainList
{
    min-height:500px;
    width:500px;
    margin:3rem auto;
    padding:30px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 0px #000;
}
.inputListName
{
    margin:1rem auto;
    min-width:100%;
}
.inputListName > .addItemHeading
{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color:#00bf8f;
}
.inputListName > hr
{
    border:1px solid #00bf8f;
    width:100px;
    padding:0px !important;
    margin:1rem auto;
}

.inputListName > input[type="text"]
{
    height:45px;
    width:65%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    float:left;
    text-align:center; 
    color:#00bf8f;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border:1px solid #0b8793;
    border-radius:10px; 
}
.inputListName > input[type="text"]:focus
{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 0px #0009;
}
.inputListName > input[type="submit"]
{
    height:45px;
    width:30%;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #0b8793;
    background:white;
    color:#0b8793;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size: 1rem;   
}
.inputListName > input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    color:white;
    background:#0b8793;
}
#errorMessage
{
    color:#c31432;
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.error-img
{
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#listContainer
{
    counter-reset: section;
}
 #listContainer > li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    padding:15px;
    height:52px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px solid #00bf8f;
    color:#00bf8f;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
#listContainer > li::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) ": ";
    color:#00f260;
  }
#listContainer > li >.closeBtn
{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    color:red;
    border:none;
    height:50px;
    width:40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    background:#00f260;
}
#listContainer > li:hover
{
    background:#00bf8f;
    color:#fff;
}
footer >h4
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #00bf8f;
    color:#fff;
    min-height:40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px)
{
    #mainList
    {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
        <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
        <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
        <title>My First TODO List.</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="app-icon.png"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
         <!--Web app manfest file for android devices-->
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#dd62ff" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="main-heading">TODO List</h1>
        <div class="list" id="mainList">
            <form class="inputListName" name="form-input" accept="index.html" >
                <h4 class="addItemHeading">Add Items To The List</h4>
                <hr/>
                <input type="text" class="inputName" placeholder="Type Task name"/>
                <input type="submit" class="submitName" value="Add"/>
                <p id="errorMessage"></p>
            </form>
            <div id="deleteAllListItem"></div>
            <ul id="listContainer"></ul>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <h4>This TODO List is Made With &hearts; By Vaibhav Kaul</h4>
        </footer>
    </body>
    <script>
        //Check if the service worker exists in the navigator object.
        if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) 
    {
        window.addEventListener("load", function() 
        {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register("service-worker.js")
            .then(res => console.log("service worker registered"))
            .catch(err => console.log("service worker not registered", err))
        })
    }
  </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please console first 
let storage = localstorage.getitem("myListItems")
console.log(storage)
And then take action on the behalf of that result

Comment: Thanks for helping but everything is working but only when I hard reload the page. Normal reloading isn't letting the browser fetch data from local storage.?

Comment: Yes i think there is async issue so ensure that when data exist then render. By using if condition